# signal handler sa_sigaction arguments

Tags: c, unix, signals

i have

```
struct sigaction pipe_act;
pipe_act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
pipe_act.sa_sigaction = sigpipehandler
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &pipe_act, NULL);
```

when i've try to write the sigpipeHandler, gcc told me that it needs three args. The second args is ok, it's siginfo_t struct that containts information about signal, bue the first and the third (an int and a void variable), what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument is the signal number. It's needed because you may use the same handler for several different signals.

The third argument contains the context that was in use when the signal was received. Contexts may be used via the `makecontext()/setcontext()/getcontext()/swapcontext()` functions to implement user-space threads. The context structure also contains non-portable architecture-specific information, e.g. the value of processor registers when the signal was received. Mess with the processor state at your own risk.

Comment: ok, so just declared dummy that two args. I'm using an handler for each signal, and i don't need to know context in my specific code case. thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The man of `sigaction` says :

> ```
>  The sigaction structure is defined as something like:
>
>        struct sigaction {
>            void     (*sa_handler)(int);
>            void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
>            sigset_t   sa_mask;
>            int        sa_flags;
>            void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
>        };  
>
>    sa_handler specifies the action to be associated with signum and may be
>    SIG_DFL for the default action, SIG_IGN to ignore  this  signal,  or  a
>    pointer to a signal handling function.  This function receives the sig‐
>    nal number as its only argument.
>
>    If SA_SIGINFO is specified in sa_flags, then sa_sigaction  (instead  of
>    sa_handler)  specifies  the  signal-handling function for signum.  This
>    function receives the signal number as its first argument, a pointer to
>    a  siginfo_t as its second argument and a pointer to a ucontext_t (cast
>    to void *) as its third argument.
>
>
>    ....
> ```
>
> > ```
> >    The siginfo_t argument to sa_sigaction is a struct with  the  following
> >    elements:
> > ```
>
> ```
>        siginfo_t {
>            int      si_signo;    /* Signal number */
>            int      si_errno;    /* An errno value */
>            int      si_code;     /* Signal code */
>            int      si_trapno;   /* Trap number that caused
>                                     hardware-generated signal
>                                     (unused on most architectures) */
>            pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
>            uid_t    si_uid;      /* Real user ID of sending process */
>            int      si_status;   /* Exit value or signal */
>            clock_t  si_utime;    /* User time consumed */
>            clock_t  si_stime;    /* System time consumed */
>            sigval_t si_value;    /* Signal value */
>            int      si_int;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
>            void    *si_ptr;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
>            int      si_overrun;  /* Timer overrun count; POSIX.1b timers */
>            int      si_timerid;  /* Timer ID; POSIX.1b timers */
>            void    *si_addr;     /* Memory location which caused fault */
>            long     si_band;     /* Band event (was int in
>                                     glibc 2.3.2 and earlier) */
>            int      si_fd;       /* File descriptor */
>            short    si_addr_lsb; /* Least significant bit of address
>                                     (since kernel 2.6.32) */
>        }
> ```

Comment: what is the necessity of first arg? if i receive (in this case) a sigpipe, and sigpipeHandler it's executed, i know that the signal number is sigpipe... and third args what is? and for what is used?

Comment: After reading this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext, I think the ucontext_t is used for saving the user context.

Comment: Does sigaction define sa_handler and sa_sigaction as a union instead of two fields? https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/sigaction.h.html